# Rashba spin orbit Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, spin-orbit

I am studying the rashba spin orbit interaction in graphene

I know the effective Hamiltonian for RSOI in the presence of a perpendicular electric field ($E_z$) is
$$
H_{RSO}=\frac{\alpha}{\hbar}(P_x\sigma_y-P_y\sigma_x)  \tag{1}
$$
where P is the momentum vector and σ is the pauli matrix vector
but there is also another form of effective Hamiltonian
$$
H_{RSO}=\frac{\lambda R}{2}(\tau\sigma_xS_y−\sigma_yS_x) \tag{2} 
$$
where $\tau=1$ and $-1$ in K and K' point. $\sigma_x$ and $\sigma_y$ are pseudospin and $S_x$ and $S_y$ are spin angular momentum in spin space

my question is that are Eq. (1) and Eq. (2) equivalent?
and how eq.(2) is derived?

Comment: you need to supply more details. For example - I'm guessing that you are talking specifically about graphene? what are the $\sigma_i$ and $S_i$ etc.?

Comment: yes i am studying rsoi in graphene. I edited the question and added more details thank you

Comment: Please check the meaning of $\sigma_{x,y}$ and $S_{x,y}$ in Eq. (2) - one should be spin operator and the other orbital momentm (angular or linear)... otherwise it wouldn't be spin-orbit coupling.